# How to specify mutual exclusion between groups of arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to implement a script `myscript.py` with the following "two-mode" signature:

```
myscript.py ARG1 ARG2 [ARG3 [ARG3 ...]]
myscript.py --foo ARG1
```

In English, this script can be called in two ways: (1) in the first way, the script has two required positional arguments, `ARG1` and `ARG2`, and can take zero or more of a third type of positional argument (`ARG3`); and (2) in the second way, the script has one required `--foo` flag and one required positional argument, `ARG1` <sup>1</sup>.

(Another way to describe this signature is that the script must receive one mandatory positional argument, `ARG1`, and *either* (1) the `--foo` flag, *or* (2) one `ARG2` positional argument followed by zero or more `ARG3` arguments.)

---

**MY QUESTION:** *Is there a way to specify this relationship among arguments using Python 3's `argparse`?*

---

I've tried two approaches to achieve this, both fail.

The first approach is this:

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('arg1')

    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

    ##########################################################################
    group.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')

    subgroup = group.add_argument_group()
    subgroup.add_argument('arg2')
    subgroup.add_argument('arg3', nargs='*')
    ##########################################################################

    parsed_args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

This approach produces the wrong behavior (or at least the wrong error messages) for certain invocations.  For example, the following (correct) invocation fails (and the error message's assertion is also incorrect):

```
% python3 myscript.py --foo 42
usage: myscript.py [-h] --foo arg1 arg2 [arg3 [arg3 ...]]
myscript.py: error: the following arguments are required: arg2, arg3
```

The second approach I tried is shown below (by the way, the code between the `###...###` divider lines is what differs between the two approaches):

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('arg1')

    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)

    ##########################################################################
    subgroup = [group.add_argument_group(), group.add_argument_group()]

    subgroup[0].add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')

    subgroup[1].add_argument('arg2')
    subgroup[1].add_argument('arg3', nargs='*')
    ##########################################################################

    parsed_args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

With this second approach, an invocation like the one above causes `argparse.py` to raise an exception.  For what it's worth, the (long-ish) stack trace ends with

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 406, in _format_actions_usage
    start = actions.index(group._group_actions[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Irrespective of which way the script is invoked, the `ARG1` argument should get assigned to the same parameter within the script.  In other words, the meta-variable `ARG1` has the same semantics, irrespective of how the script is invoked.</sup>

Comment: `argument_group` does not nest meaningfully within a `mutually_exclusive_group`.  `argument_group` is only used for help display.  It does nothing during parsing.  You have to do your own checking after parsing.

Comment: A quick suggestion: `ARG1` as required positional; `--foo` as store_true optional, `ARG2` as a '*' positional.  After parsing check `--foo` against the `len` of `arg2`.